# Possible to have Infopath form deployed in a feature? SP2010/VS2010

Tags: infopath, feature, custom-form

I'm using new VS2010 Sharepoint Project. I can add a site column, content type, list definition without any problem.

Is it possible to also have an InfoPath form included in a Feature?

I want to be able to create the form using InfoPath, somehow export it, somehow get it into the feature definition so it can be compliled in the WSP package.

Once I have this I would like to bind it to a list instance / defininition view item field.

Anyone done this yet? Is it even possible, and if yes how?

Comment: Is it a workflow form or a template for a forms library or something else?

Comment: It is the edit form for a list item in a custom list.

Answer (score 1):

In VS2008 we were actually able to do InfoPath development using an InfoPath add-in. They took this functionality away in VS2010 for some reason. I don't believe it would have helped you anyway as the form could still not be included in a feature.

It is less than ideal, but I think the best you are going to be able to do is to deploy the form template using PowerShell. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262921.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post: http://www.stuartroberts.net/index.php/2010/12/14/programatically-register-infopath-form-for-web-browsing-in-sharepoint/

Hope that is what you're looking for.